# AWS SAM Deploy not updating layer version correctly

Tags: aws-sam

Currently deploying to AWS using SAM. When referencing a Layer SAM doesnt seem to update the variable correctly?

template.yaml

```
Parameters:
  HelperFunctionsLayer:
    Type: String
    Default: layer-helper-functions:69

...

Outputs:
  HelperFunctionsLayer:
    Value: !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:layer:${HelperFunctionsLayer}'
```

Output from sam deploy:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Outputs                                                                                         
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key                 HelperFunctionsLayer                                                        
Description         -                                                                           
Value               arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:000000000000:layer:layer-helper-functions:22       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Notice the version has not updated. We are deploying via GitLab runner could a version of the config be kept and not updated somewhere?

EDIT: Have now also reproduced locally without GitLab...

EDIT1: In the deployment the function does get updated but the version does not change.

The only current way we can this to work is to name the layer explicitly however this is referenced quite a few times in the template.yaml
[image: GitLab Snippet]

Comment: Hi, any solution?

Comment: Not currently. The only way to get it to work for me is to delete the whole stack and redeploy it

Comment: Add a description. Any time the description or any other property of the layer changes will force it to update. It's a hack but it is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

consider using the --force-upload flag of sam deploy

Answer (score 0):

Changing the parameter name is what finally did it for me. Kind of annoying but careful search and replace did it. So `HelperFunctionsLayer` could be renamed to something like `HelperFunctionsLayerNew`.